# I'm trying to Decode a JSON file locally in my program, but keep getting Error

Tags: swift, swift4, jsondecoder

I'm trying to use JSON Decoder in Swift 4.1 but I keep getting

> "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format"

and I have no idea why. I'm calling a JSON file from the `Bundle.main.path` and then setting that to a variable after calling it in the `URL(fileURLWithPath:)`.

Looking at the file path and opening it locally, it seems that the JSON data is in the proper format. In my *data.json* file, the data is setup like this.

```
{
    "plant": "1015",
    "name": "SPEEDVALE",
    "key": "5035",
}
```

I have a struct that looks like this

```
struct AllData: Decodable {
    let plant: String
    let name: String
    let key: String
}
```

Then I have a variable that declared as this

```
private var x: [AllData] = []
```

And then the decoding block of code looks like this

```
do {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json")
    let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))

    do {
        plantDataSerialized = try [JSONDecoder().decode(AllData.self, from: jsonData)]
        print(plantDataSerialized)
    } catch let error{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format" ?

Comment: that's just the error that comes up in the console. It goes into the first catch let error scope when I debug

Comment: I have executed your code and its giving the correct result 
[__lldb_expr_69.AllData(plant: "1015", name: "SPEEDVALE", key: "5035")]

Comment: @SamaBalaYam  can you tell me how you were able to display the data after reading a file  in console ? I was also trying to figure this out.

Comment: do it like
private var x: [AllData] = []
 ......
 .....
 x = try [JSONDecoder().decode(AllData.self, from: jsonData)]
        print(x)

Comment: still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

I think your JSON have the array of key-value pairs so you are doing decoding in a wrong way. You have to do like this:

```
plantDataSerialized = try JSONDecoder().decode([AllData].self, from: jsonData)
```

If your JSON does not have the array of key-value pairs then You need to do like this:

```
plantDataSerialized = try JSONDecoder().decode(AllData.self, from: jsonData)
```

Comment: Then I get "Cannot assign value of type 'AllData' to type '[AllData]'" So I tried to make plantDataSerialized: AllData? but that didn't work.

Comment: @simonmcneil  plantDataSerialized has the array of AllData. Means plantDataSerialized will auto get the response in  [AllData]. You don't need to use another variable.

Answer (score 1):

you have error in reading file so just use it like this

```
guard let  jsonFile =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json") else { return}

guard  let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: jsonFile), options: []) else {return}


                do {
                    let plantDataSerialized = try [JSONDecoder().decode(AllData.self, from: data)]
                    print(plantDataSerialized)
                } catch let error{
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
```